# Is this a bug in the Mac OS X 10.6 C++ std API?

Tags: c++, macos

The following code won't compile on Mac OS X 10.6; it gives an error in stl_algobase.h following a list of "instantiated from [...]" messages.

```
#include <vector>

int main( void )
{
    std::vector<int*> *v = new std::vector<int*>( 1, NULL );

    return 0;
}
```

In order to make it compile, I have to place an explicit cast around `NULL`, i.e. replace it with `(int*)(NULL)`.
That looks kind of awkward, though, and I doubt it should be really necessary; it also makes my source code look quite weird with structures and longer type names nested in namespaces, etc.

EDIT (Error message):

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h: In static member function 'static _OutputIterator std::__fill_n<true>::fill_n(_OutputIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _OutputIterator = int**, _Size = int, _Tp = int]':
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:665:   instantiated from '_OutputIterator std::fill_n(_OutputIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _OutputIterator = int**, _Size = int, _Tp = int]'
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:184:   instantiated from 'void std::__uninitialized_fill_n_aux(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&, std::__true_type) [with _ForwardIterator = int**, _Size = int, _Tp = int]'
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:219:   instantiated from 'void std::uninitialized_fill_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = int**, _Size = int, _Tp = int]'  
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:306:   instantiated from 'void std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&, std::allocator<_Tp2>) [with _ForwardIterator = int**, _Size = int, _Tp = int, _Tp2 = int*]'  
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:790:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_dispatch(_Integer, _Integer, std::__true_type) [with _Integer = int, _Tp = int*, _Alloc = std::allocator<int*>]'  
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:261:   instantiated from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Alloc&) [with _InputIterator = int, _Tp = int*, _Alloc = std::allocator<int*>]'  
/Users/JayZ/projects/C++/test/main.cpp:6:   instantiated from here
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:641: error: invalid conversion from 'const int' to 'int*'
```

If that could help...

Comment: It would help us answer if you posted the actual error message...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is that the compiler has to select between one of the `vector` constructor overloads that allows more than one argument:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(),
    const Allocator& = Allocator());

template <class InputIterator>
    vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
        const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

The first overload (which you want to match) requires that the arguments be converted.  The second requires no conversion, since the 2 arguments are the same type.  So that's the overload the compiler is choosing.  Unfortunately, the `int` type doesn't have all the operations that the second constructor uses for those arguments.

Forcing the arguments to be different types by casting `NULL` to `int*` or by making the first argument unsigned (`1U`) as other answers correctly suggest will avoid the problem by forcing the compiler to select the first constructor option.

Update:

When I compile this with MinGW 4.5.2 I get compile errors (different ones, but for the same reason, I believe).  However, when I build with MSVC (2008 or 2010), I get no errors. When I look into the code that MSVC generates, it is actually matching the second overload (with 2 iterators) not the 'size and default value' overload.

"Aha", I think, "this is going to crash at runtime somewhere, because iterators with the value `1` and `0` don't make any sense".

However, when the 'iterator' types of that constructor happen to be `int`, the MSVC implementation performs a 'count/initial value' construction of the `vector`.

The standard says what that constructor must do when the `InputIterator` arguments of the constructor meet the requirements of an InputIterator.  Since `int` doesn't meet the requirements of an InputIterator, the implementation has some free reign to do something else. The standard says that "An implementation can declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class" (17.4.4.4), and this would cover MSVC's behavior, I believe. The behavior that you're seeing and that I see with GCC 4.5.2, producing an error diagnostic, is also permitted by the standard.

I'm sure MSVC's behavior is what most users intend and want (until they move to the code to some other compiler maybe).  And it's certainly clever.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I completely forgot pointers can work as iterators in vectors. I guess I should read the error messages more thouroughly ;)

Comment: +1 for an excellent explanation of *why* we're seeing this error. Would give another +1 if I could for the extra investigation with MSVC++.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted compiles for me on OS X 10.6.7. I added in some assertions just to prove that it is doing what it looks like it should be...

```
bash-3.2$ cat test.cpp 
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> *v = new std::vector<int*>( 1, NULL );
    assert(v != NULL);
    assert(v->size() == 1);
    assert(v->at(0) == NULL);
    assert(false);
    return 0;
}  

bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ test.cpp 
bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
Assertion failed: (false), function main, file test.cpp, line 10.
Abort trap
bash-3.2$ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The `assert(false)` is deliberate :-)

With thanks to [Mackie Messer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606091/is-this-a-bug-in-the-mac-os-x-10-6-c-std-api/5606251#5606251) I can reproduce your error with `-m32`. This line fixes it (and is neater than casting IMHO):

```
std::vector<int*> *v = new std::vector<int*>(1U, NULL);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: interesting... I tried it from the command line as well. But I'm getting the same error messages as before (replaceing the /Developer stuff with /usr...). Are you using XCode 4?

Comment: @iolo: I must confess that I am not.